# Comma does not separate lines of print in python34 on windows8?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, windows-8.1

I am learning python34 and I read here in my course book the following line:

"The comma separating the two print() commands in this file instructs Python to no start a new
line."

I am guessing by "no" they actually mean not?

Using the next script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3 

print ("Hello from a Python file!"),
print ("Welcome to Python!")
```

And I have the following example of its execution on mac:

```
$ python3 ~/Desktop/Python/Hello.py
Hello from a Python file! Welcome to Python!
```

But my windows8 gives me this output:

```
c:\f>a.py
Hello from a Python file!
Welcome to Python!
```

I am running the file via cmd without the Python command (as shown above), since it doesn't work otherwise...
I added manually the system Environment Variables path to Python default installation
folder (C:\Python34)

Comment: What is the name of course book, The notation is for python 2 and not python3

Comment: Python 2.x doesn't allow comma usage whereas Python 3.x allows both (comma and lines) to separate print out statements into each new line.

Comment: It is something internal nothing official but I believe it is based on the python documentation with changes though and it is updated when needed, so I am really not sure where it was taken from anymore.

@hagubear
What do u mean python 2.x doesn't allot comma usage if it is a notation of python 2? I am puzzled...and I read it is suppoused to prevent a new line but u say it should cause a new line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comma doesn't work in Python3, see [what's new in Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3.4/whatsnew/3.0.html#print-is-a-function). Also see the [docs for print function in Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print).

```
Old: print x,           # Trailing comma suppresses newline
New: print(x, end=" ")  # Appends a space instead of a newline
```

Your example would be:

```
>>> def test():
...   print("Hello from a Python file!", end=" ")
...   print("Welcome to Python!")
...
>>> test()
Hello from a Python file! Welcome to Python!
```

Answer (score 0):

Output in Python3

```
Hello from a Python file!
Welcome to Python!
```

Output in Python2

```
Hello from a Python file! Welcome to Python!
```

This is because the `comma` notation has been removed as `print` has been made a function in 3 whereas it was a keyword in 2.

You can achieve what you want by using

```
print ("Hello from a Python file!",end = ' ')
print ("Welcome to Python!")
```

This making use of keyword arguments of the `print` function in python3

Comment: end = ',' doesn't give the same output as Python 2's print with comma at the end

Comment: @miles82 Oh yeah, `end = ','` will print `Hello from a Python file!,Welcome to Python!`